# How to call a C++ function from C code

Tags: c++, c

I have a C++ class with its header CFileMapping.cpp and CFileMapping.h I want to call the c++ function `CFileMapping::getInstance().writeMemory( )` in my C code.

Even when I wrapped my C++ code and added

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
```

in the header file to deal with the c++ code and added
    extern "C"
in the cpp file, I still can't call my function like this

```
CFileMapping::getInstance().writeMemory().
```

Could any one help me? I want to keep my c++ code and be able to call it when I want.

Answer (score 4):

You should create C wrapper for your C++ call:

```
extern "C" 
{
  void WriteMemFile() 
  {
    CFileMapping::getInstance().writeMemory( );
  }
}

// The C interface
void WriteMemFile();
```

**IMPORTANT:** The `extern "C"` specifies that the function uses the C naming conventions.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I am having an error in the .cpp file `FileMapping.cpp:(.text+0x1014): undefined reference to std::cout `
. Even if i added the using namespace std; after extern "C"

Comment: you need to compile it using C++ compiler, not C compiler and then you'll be able to call this library function from C code

Comment: @Emb_user Read carefully the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c

Comment: I fixed my problem. My program works now .Thanks a lot .